# Heroku VULNERABLE (DoS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I was testing all my apps for the Heartbleed bug using sslanalyzer.comodoca.com. In doing so I noticed a number of rails 4 apps I am running on Heroku are open to Secure Renegotiation  (Client-initiated) VULNERABLE (DoS)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,

Cory

Comment: I recommend opening a ticket with [Heroku Support](https://help.heroku.com/).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140407.txt) news article you can recompile OpenSSL with the option -DOPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS, or just upgrade to **OpenSSL 1.0.1g**.

**[EDIT]** Heroku [states](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/606) that they fixed the Heartbleed issue. Apparently, before they fixed it, they offered rotating database credentials as a solution:

**heroku pg:credentials --reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLORHERE**

or

> We strongly advise customers with apps that use SSL Endpoint to generate a new private key, then use the new key to have the certificate reissued by its issuer. With the newly signed certificate, proceed to [update your SSL endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#update-certificate).

Comment: This question isn't about heartbleed.  The OP states that *while* searching for heartbleed vulnerabilities, the analyzer he was using gave him a warning about an entirely different issue.

Comment: I apologize for the answer then.